# How to modularize Vuex into different folders and files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have been looking into the vuex module, then figured I could try something like creating as many modules(dir) as I want and have the action, getters, mutations and state separated into different files.

I have the vuex structure as:

```
.
└── src/
    ├── store/
    │   ├── moduels/
    │   │   └── todo/
    │   │       ├── state.js
    │   │       ├── getters.js
    │   │       ├── actions.js
    │   │       ├── mutations.js
    │   │       └── index.js
    │   └── index.js
    └── main.js
```

**State**

```js
export const state =  () => {
    return {
        todos: []
    }
}
```

**getters**

```js
export const getters = {
    allTodos: (state) => state.todos
}
```

**actions**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { ALL_TODOS } from "@/store/mutation-types.js";

export const actions =  {
    async getTodos({ commit }){
        let page_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
        const res = await axios.get(page_url);
        console.log(res.data);
        commit(ALL_TODOS, res.data)
    }
}
```

**Mutations**

```js
import { ALL_TODOS } from "@/store/mutation-types.js";

export const mutations =  {
    [ALL_TODOS]: (state, todos) => state.todos = todos
}
```

**todo/index.js**

```js
import state from './state.js';
import getters from './getters.js';
import actions from './actions.js';
import mutations from './mutations.js';

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
  };
```

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Todo from './modules/todo';

Vue.use(Vuex)

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        namespaced: true,
        modules: {
            Todo
        }
    });
}

export default createStore
```

**src/main.js**

```js
import store from './store/index';
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store
}).$mount('#app')
```

**That done,** if tried to use it anywhere in my code like so:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['allTodos'])
},
created () {
   this.$store.dispatch('todo/getTodos')
},
methods: {
 ...mapActions(['getTodos']),
}
```

i get an error
`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"`

i have also tried changing `this.$store.dispatch('todo/getTodos')` to `this.getTodos` but it won't work

**Updated**

so i realized there was a problem with my vue installation i re-installed it and created a new project with same structure as earlier and made some few changes to the code but still got an error `[vuex] unknown action type: todo/fetchTodos`

**here is my code**

state and getters are the same as the previous

***actions.js***

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { TODOS } from '../../mutation-type'

export const actions = {
    async fetchTodos(context){
        let page_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
        const res = await axios.get(page_url);
        console.log(res.data);

        context.commit(TODOS, res.data)
    }
}
```

***mutations.js***

```js
import { TODOS } from '../../mutation-type'

export const mutations = {
    [TODOS]: (state, todos) => state.todos = todos
}
```

***modules/todo/index.js***

```js
import state from './state';
import getters from './getters';
import actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';

export default {
    namespace: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

***store/index.js***

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import Todo from './modules/todo';

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    Todo
  }
})
```

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

and in vue file as follows:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      todo: 'todo/getTodos'
    })
  },
  created(){
    this.$store.dispatch('todo/fetchTodos')
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions['fetchTodos']
  }
```

Comment: The error seems very intuitive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` which means that `this.$store` is not defined, so the problem has not to do with your vuex store at that point.

Comment: @courage Show your `main.js`, where you actually use `store/index.js`.

Comment: @tony19 I have deleted the whole project and started over. seems vue.js was not properly installed

Comment: So the problem is no longer reproducible?

Comment: i just finished with the installation. haven't tried to reproduce it yet

Comment: i just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `store/index.js` is exporting the `createStore` function and not the store itself. You should execute the function to get the store object in the `main.js` as follows:

```
import store from './store/index';
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store: store()
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: After your update, I'm not sure, but you're registering the todo module as Todo and referring to it as todo without capital T.

Comment: the problem is with `export` it should be `export default`. only problem is the action returns undefined

Comment: I think it should be `Todo/getTodos`. As the name of the module starts with a capital T in your modules definition.